# What are the special advantages of regression method of forecasting over others

Tags: analysis, strategy

In Quantitative Forecasting, there are different methods to predict the future. How Regression Analysis is more special than:

- Simple moving average
- Weighted moving average
- exponential smoothing

and what is its advantages ?

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not believe there is an answer to this question.  All predictive models have a predictive validity of something less than perfect.  Certainly, some models or techniques are better than others but of those indicated in the OP (original post) I am not sure that is the case.  In PM, I run several models because each would provide a datum that, together, gives me the range of possible future results.

This is completely my opinion and it works for me and, since no one else tried to answer, I thought I would put it out there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what do you mean by OP ?

Comment: OP = original post.